# When do we use gblinear versus gbtree?

Tags: boosting

When do we choose gblinear boosting or gbtree boosting in xgboost library. I have a meteorological rain data with lots of missing values.

Answer (score 1):

If we think that we should be using a gradient boosting implementation like XGBoost, the answer on when to use [`gblinear`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html#parameters-for-linear-booster-booster-gblinear) instead of `gbtree` is: "probably never". With `gblinear`  we will get an elastic-net fit equivalent and essentially create a single linear regularised model. Unless we are dealing with a task we would expect/know that a LASSO/ridge/elastic-net regression is already competitive, it does not worth our trouble aside maybe if we have already in place a data pipeline serving an XGBoost model and we want to try a GLM quickly. That said though, R, Python, MATLAB, Julia, etc. have better and more well-developed specialised routines to fit elastic-net regression tasks.The CV.SE thread: *[Difference in regression coefficients of sklearn's LinearRegression and XGBRegressor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/448879/difference-in-regression-coefficients-of-sklearns-linearregression-and-xgbregre)* provides further details on comparing XGBoost's `gblinear` to a standard linear regression.

Note if we believe some linear relation to be present at a low/local level, LightGBM's argument [`lineartree`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#linear_tree) is emulating the methodology of [Cubist](https://www.rulequest.com/cubist-info.html) (or M5) where a tree is grown such that the terminal leaves contain linear regression models. This is structurally different to `gblinear` though as it is first and foremost a tree rather than a regularised linear model.